# Formatting of TikZ matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I would like to use TikZ in order to format a table. My goal is to get a table of 4 columns whose overall width is `\texwidth` (I managed to get almost this by setting the minimum length to `0.25\texwidth`, though i guess this is not the best was, since it creates a bad box).

On this table I would like to have the text aligned left and an overlay over some cells, but I would like the overlay to cover the whole cell. After changing some code I found here I got the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,tikzmark}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,decorations.pathreplacing,calc}
\usepackage{hf-tikz}

\pgfkeys{tikz/mymatrix/.style={matrix of nodes,nodes in empty cells,left,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,column sep=0pt,row sep=0pt,nodes={align=left,minimum width=0.25\textwidth,minimum height=10pt,anchor=center,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt}}}

\tikzset{style green/.style={
    set fill color=green!50!lime!60,draw opacity=0.4,
    set border color=green!50!lime!60,fill opacity=0.1,
  },
  style cyan/.style={
    set fill color=cyan!90!blue!60, draw opacity=0.4,
    set border color=blue!70!cyan!30,fill opacity=0.1,
  },
  style orange/.style={
    set fill color=orange!90, draw opacity=0.8,
    set border color=orange!90, fill opacity=0.3,
  },
  style brown/.style={
    set fill color=brown!70!orange!40, draw opacity=0.4,
    set border color=brown, fill opacity=0.3,
  },
  style purple/.style={
    set fill color=violet!90!pink!20, draw opacity=0.5,
    set border color=violet, fill opacity=0.3,    
  },
  cll/.style={
    above left offset={-0.1,0.15},
    below right offset={0.10,-0.17},
    #1
  },set fill color/.code={\pgfkeysalso{fill=#1}},
  set border color/.style={draw=#1}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={-1ex}]
\matrix [mymatrix,inner sep=0pt] (m)  
{
\tikzmarkin[cll=style green]{first}11 11&12&13&14\tikzmarkend{first}\\
\tikzmarkin[cll=style orange]{second}21&22&23\tikzmarkend{second}&24\\
\tikzmarkin[cll=style cyan]{third}31&32&33&34\tikzmarkend{third}\\
41&\tikzmarkin[cll=style brown]{fourth}42\tikzmarkend{fourth}&43&44\\   
};
\end{tikzpicture}  

\vspace{1em}

\lipsum[1-1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Currently I am unable to get the overlay to cover the whole cell, for example it starts right before the text in 11 and stops right after the text in cell 14. How can this be done? Changing anchor and\or align doesn't do anything. Also how can I force the matrix to have fixes overall width?

Comment: Please note that you should never use `\tikzmarkin` inside a `tikzpicture`. So you may either work with an amsmath matrix and `\tikzmarkin` inside, or go along the lines of Ignasis nice answer, which may be the more elegant and more powerful approach.

Comment: Oh, I had no clue. Is there an easy explanation why it should only be used with an amsmath matrix?

Comment: The restriction is not "only with amsmath matrices" but "not inside a `tikzpicture`". The reason is that the latter nests `tizpicture`s, which is not supported and can have uncontrollable side effects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have already defined the nodes with the correct size, but `tikz-markin` references are placed just before and after the text, without considering node's size.

Therefore, I suggest to use `fitting` nodes (from `fit` library) which draw nodes around other nodes, considering their complete size.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,tikzmark, fit}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,decorations.pathreplacing,calc}
\usepackage{hf-tikz}

\pgfkeys{tikz/mymatrix/.style={matrix of nodes,nodes in empty cells,left,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,column sep=0pt,row sep=0pt,nodes={align=left,minimum width=0.25\textwidth,minimum height=10pt,anchor=center,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt}}}

\tikzset{style green/.style={
    set fill color=green!50!lime!60,draw opacity=0.4,
    set border color=green!50!lime!60,fill opacity=0.1,
  },
  style cyan/.style={
    set fill color=cyan!90!blue!60, draw opacity=0.4,
    set border color=blue!70!cyan!30,fill opacity=0.1,
  },
  style orange/.style={
    set fill color=orange!90, draw opacity=0.8,
    set border color=orange!90, fill opacity=0.3,
  },
  style brown/.style={
    set fill color=brown!70!orange!40, draw opacity=0.4,
    set border color=brown, fill opacity=0.3,
  },
  style purple/.style={
    set fill color=violet!90!pink!20, draw opacity=0.5,
    set border color=violet, fill opacity=0.3,    
  },
  cll/.style={
    above left offset={-0.1,0.15},
    below right offset={0.10,-0.17},
    #1
  },set fill color/.code={\pgfkeysalso{fill=#1}},
  set border color/.style={draw=#1}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={-1ex}]
\matrix [mymatrix,inner sep=0pt] (m)  
{
11 11&12&13&14\\
21&22&23&24\\
31&32&33&34\\
41&42&43&44\\   
};
\node[rounded corners, style green, fit=(m-1-1) (m-1-4), inner sep=0pt] {};
\node[rounded corners, style orange, fit=(m-2-1) (m-2-3), inner sep=0pt] {};
\node[rounded corners, style cyan, fit=(m-3-1) (m-3-4), inner sep=0pt]{};
\node[rounded corners, style brown, fit=(m-4-2), inner sep=0pt]{};
\end{tikzpicture}  

\vspace{1em}

\lipsum[1-1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, that's great! Thank you. Is there also any way to align the text to the left?

Comment: @tst Replace `minimum width` by `text width` in `nodes` declaration.